# Sifr IE6+IE7 Error/not working

Tags: internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, sifr

I've been trying to get Sifr3 to work for hours now, it works fine in Safari and Firefox, but doesn't in IE6 & IE7.

I've checked the Flash version + found somewhere the problem could lay in media="" definition which i added.

Here are the codes I use:

> sIFR.prefetch({
>       src: 'myriad.swf'   }, {
>       src: 'myriader.swf'   });
>   
>   sIFR.compatMode = true;
>   sIFR.activate();
>   
>   sIFR.replace({ selector: 'h1.pak',
>   src: 'myriad.swf', css: { 
>   '.sIFR-root' : { 'color': '#ed1c24',
>   'font-weight': 'normal' }, }, wmode:
>   'transparent', paddingTop: 10 });
>   
>   sIFR.replace({ selector:
>   'h2.pak,h3.pak', src: 'myriader.swf',
>   css: {  '.sIFR-root' : { 'color':
>   '#ed1c24', 'font-weight': 'normal' },
>   }, wmode: 'transparent', paddingTop: 0
>   });

If you want to have a look at the page you can go here: [www.e-mkb.nl/pakketten.htm](http://www.e-mkb.nl/pakketten.htm)

I really hope someone will be able to help me out on this.
Thanks in advance,

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

You're using 3.0 alpha 1, which you really shouldn't. [r436](http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/nightlies/) is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get sIFR 3 r436 to work with IE. IE gives some generic javascript error. Removing wmode: 'transparent' seems to help but I still need that wmode for lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: http://www.mikebuckley.me/2009/10/sifr-transparent-wmode-in-ie6/

basically you just need to add the following code line after sIFR.activate(..); :

sIFR.repaintOnResize = false;